# What's the right way to implement virtual function in some derived classes?

Tags: c++, oop, c++11

I have an abstract class `A` that contains a *pure virtual method*.

```
class A
{
 public:
   virtual A* doWork() = 0;
}
```

I have two classes derived from the class `A` (they aren't abstract classes).
It's necessary to implement the pure virtual function `doWork()` inside these two classes.

But I want to implement this function just in one class (class `B`, for example), and these two classes must be derive from `A`.

```
class B :public A
{
  A* doWork()
  {
    A* a = new B();
    // do some work
    return a;
  }
}
```

What I want when I call `doWork()` in class `C` is to print some text that says this function isn't implemented here.

```
class C : public A
{
  A* doWork()
  {
    // I want just to print some text and I don't want          
    // to return anything.
  }
}
```

I tried to throw an error but this is not what I want to do.

Is there a better way to do that?

Comment: You can just print warning and return `null` if invoker can handle `null`

Comment: `B::` should not be present in `B`. Same for `C`. And it's `class`, not `Class`.

Answer (score 0):

One option, challenging the premise of making class A abstract, assuming you have control over that: don't make class A abstract and implement a default function there.  You have to return something, but it could be a null pointer.  output of function in class A will indicate that function has not been implemented, which would be accurate.

```
class A
{
 public:
        virtual A* doWork() 
        {
            cout << "Warning: doWork not implemented" << endl;
            return (A*)0;
        }
}
```

Comment: ... or more technically, cout should say that doWork() is not overridden!

Comment: `nullptr` without cast would be ... better?

Comment: @knivil - certainly, as long as we're on the subject of good practice and style, but nullptr does assume a recent version of C++.  To be sure, the old C style cast I threw in was lazy typing!

Answer (score 0):

I would say your design is flawed, but you could possibly go around it by increasing the class hierarchy to something like

```
class A
{
    ...
};

class A1 : public A
{
public:
    virtual A* doWork() = 0;
};

class A2 : public A
{
public:
    virtual void doWork() = 0;
};

class B : public A1
{
public:
    A* doWork() { ... }
};

class C : public A2
{
public:
    void doWork() { ... }
};
```

It's still a bad design but it should allow you to have different classes that do different things but still have both inherit from `A`.

Of course, you can't expect polymorphism to work as expected, since `A` doesn't have a `doWork` member, instead you need to downcast the `A` pointers you have to `B` or `C` pointers.